# How to make a credit card validation prior to a authorization

Tags: authorize.net, credit-card

I am using Authorize.net as a payment gateway. Now I want to check credit card validity before creating authorize payment. I am using another service to store and manage the customer's profiles and credit cards, and therefore I don't want to create a customer profile in Authorize.net, I just want to use their service to validate a credit card and later to authorize a payment.

Is there any proper way to do this validation?
Searching the documentation and other similar questions, all I could find was the option to create a customer profile, but this option doesn't seem practical to me, since it's necessary to create a customer profile, and after delete it each time I need to validate a credit card.

Does anyone had a similar problem with Authorize.net payment gateway?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do websites determine if a credit card number is valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59083356/how-do-websites-determine-if-a-credit-card-number-is-valid)

Comment: @john Conde No, I am aware of what it is a credit card validation and how is done. My question is specific to the Authorize.net gateway.

Comment: There is nothing specific to Authorize.Net here. How you validate a credit card is universal.

Comment: Yes it it's. This is not a credit card number validation, it's a actual validation of the credit card information on the payment gateway.

Comment: Payment gateways don't validate credit cards. Card issuing banks do. The gateways just pass the information through.

Comment: I know that. And I am using Authorize.net to pass my information through.

Comment: And that link tells you what you need to do to make that happen

Comment: No it doesn't. It explains how to do a credit card number validation using the Luhn algorithm and the BIN number. It also mentions what it's the AUTH ONLY validation. Now  to do a AUTH ONLY validation you actually needs a payment gateway like Authorize.net. I am using Authorize.net to do the AUTH ONLY validation. I need to know the proper payload to do this validation using the Authorize.net gateway. It's that clear to you?

Comment: An auth_only is just like a regular transaction. Have you read their documentation? It's really good and clearly explains how to do one.